# Is it possible to rewrite this RQL query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, rethinkdb

I have documents of the format:

```
{
  a: "some-value",
  b: "some-other-value",
  c: {"subfield1": "val1", "subfield2": "val2", ..}
}
```

and would like to produce output that looks like so, using MongoDB:

```
{
  "some-value": {
    "some-other-value": {"subfield1": "val1", "subfield2": "val2"},
    ..
  }, 
  ..
}
```

In RethinkDB, this query works:

```
r.table("some_table").getAll("some-value", "some-value-2",.., index: :some_index).map{ |d|
  r.object(
    d['a'],
      r.object(
        d['b'],
        d['c'].pluck("subfield1", "subfield2")
      )
    )
}.reduce{|left,right| left.merge(right)}.default({})
```

Is there a way to achieve the same using a Mongo query?

Note that there are 2 parts to this:

1. mapping all result to the nested hash
2. slicing the hash stored under field `c`

Comment: There will be [$arrayToObject](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23310) in v3.6. For now, it is only mapReduce.

Comment: @AlexBlex How would you do this using mapReduce in Mongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Javascript to re-shape document in `map` function:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function(){
        emit(this._id, {
            [this.a]: {
                [this.b]: (({ subfield1, subfield2 }) => ({ subfield1, subfield2 }))(this.c)
            }
        });
    },
    function(){},
    {out: {inline: 1}}
).results.map(function(doc){return doc.value})
```

**EDIT** a bit more wordy:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function(){
        emit(this._id, {
            [this.a]: {
                [this.b]: { subfield1: this.c.subfield1, subfield2: this.c.subfield2}
            }
        });
    },
    function(){},
    {out: {inline: 1}}
).results.map(function(doc){return doc.value})
```

**EDIT 2** return as a single object using reduce function:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function(){
        emit(null, {
            [this.a]: {
                [this.b]: (({ subfield1, subfield2 }) => ({ subfield1, subfield2 }))(this.c)
            }
        });
    },
    function(key, val){
        var res = {};
        val.forEach(function(doc) {
            // You may want to resolve conflicts here, if you have
            // more than 1 document with the same values for a and b.
            // In this code the later overwrites the former
            res = Object.assig(res, doc);
        });
        return res;
    },
    {out: {inline: 1}}
).results[0].value
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting an `Unexpected token [` error -- any clue? ( Sorry not very familiar with this syntax )

Comment: which version of the db? `db.version();`

Comment: The version is  3.4.4

Comment: are you using robomongo, by a chance?

Comment: Indeed I was :)

Comment: So running it in the mongo shell produces a different error: `SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):5:47`

I believe that's referring to the `{ subfield1, subfield2 }`

Comment: hmm, tested on 3.4.4 still works. See my edit, if more explicit syntax works.

Comment: Works like a charm now! Thanks so much!

Comment: How would I go about merging the resulting array of hashes into just one hash? Is it possible to merge them in the reducer function?

Comment: Yes, of course. Either in mongo reducer (the empty function in the example), or in javascript (replace the `map` in the example firth `reduce`).

Comment: Using javascript, this works: `reduce(function(acc, x) {
  for (var key in x.value) acc[key] = x.value[key];
  return acc;
}, {})`

How would I do the same using just the reducer function?

Comment: pretty much the same, you just need to `emit` the key in the mapper, instead of _id, and add few type-checks, since the function may be invoked more than once for the same key: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#requirements-for-the-reduce-function

Comment: I've tried that, however cannot get it to output just one hash instead of an array of hashes.

Comment: I have added an example how to use mongo reducer. Please make sure you resolve conflicts, if any. The code in the example does exactly what your javascript reducer does, which may result with some data loss.